# Can you still upgrade from Windows 7 Professional to Windows 7 Ultimate without reinstall?

Tags: windows-7, windows

My 4yo Thinkpad T500 has died and I'm planning to get a new T530 with Windows 7.  Lenovo is only shipping Win 7 Pro on it (I would have preferred Win 7 Ultimate).

So, especially now that Win 8 is out, is Microsoft still allowing people to Upgrade from Win 7 Pro to Win 7 Ultimate w/o reinstalling (Anytime Upgrade, or whatever it was called)?  Many  links that used to point to the Win 7 Anytime upgrade pages are now dead so I'm worried Microsoft has killed this off now that Win 8 has been released.

Anyone know for sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked mine and apparently you still can. Just open the Windows Anytime Upgrade and click the Buy button, and you enter all the information in that window so you may not find these links online.
[image]

[image]

[image]